# Combining a 'where' clause with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

In my app, a `Team` `belongs_to :hunt`. Once a `Hunt` is confirmed, then all associated teams are ready.

This a sample from my `team.rb` file, where I use the method `ready?` to check if `team.hunt` is confirmed.

```
#team.rb

def ready?
  hunt.confirmed? ? true : false
end
```

I would love to have a scope in `team.rb` file so I can call `Teams.all.ready.count` to show the number of teams that are ready.

How can I write a method or a scope to achieve the behaviour above without adding anything to my DB or iterating through an array etc?

Comment: Which version of rails do you use?

Comment: @guitarman currently Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: @MikeHolford Is `confirmed?` a column on `hunts` database table?

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy in this case yes but I'd love to know a solution if it wasn't too as it's a common problem for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated:

Thanks to @TomLord's insight, you'd rather do Solution 1 below instead of Solution 2. Also, added sample SQL to show comparison.

### Solution 1

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hunt
  scope :ready, -> { joins(:hunt).where(hunts: { confirmed: true }) }
end
```

*Usage:*

```
Team.ready # or: Team.all.ready
# SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "hunts" ON "hunts"."id" = "teams"."hunt_id" WHERE "hunts"."confirmed" = ? LIMIT ?  [["confirmed", "t"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

### Or, Solution 2

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hunt
end

class Hunt < ApplicationRecord
  scope :confirmed, -> { where(confirmed: true) }
end
```

*Usage:*

```
# you can also move the logic below as a method/scope inside `Team` model (i.e. as `ready` method/scope)

# Example 1 (using JOINS):
Team.joins(:hunt).where(hunts: { id: Hunt.confirmed })
# SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "hunts" ON "hunts"."id" = "teams"."hunt_id" WHERE "hunts"."id" IN (SELECT "hunts"."id" FROM "hunts" WHERE "hunts"."confirmed" = ?) LIMIT ?  [["confirmed", "t"], ["LIMIT", 11]]

# Example 2 (same as Example 1 above but faster and more efficient):
Team.where(hunt_id: Hunt.confirmed)
# SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."hunt_id" IN (SELECT "hunts"."id" FROM "hunts" WHERE "hunts"."confirmed" = ?) LIMIT ?  [["confirmed", "t"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: I'd *strongly* prefer option 1 above. Option 2 is less performant, and does not scale. (Think about what would happen in a large application, with millions of `Hunt` records!!)

Comment: @TomLord Very good point. I'll update my answer :) Sometimes I use Option 2 if the scope is complex, and that I'd rather want the logic of the scopes be modular by putting them as scopes in their corresponding models, acknowledging though that this affects performance. Although I didnt know that it "greatly" affects performance/memory usage as you have just said. Thanks for this info! I'll run some tests to check the potential impact of this :) And oh, I think I can further optimise Solution 2. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: The performance issue only really comes into play on a large system. (My day job is dealing with an application with millions of active users, and billions of database records!!) For a personal/small-scale project, you'll likely not notice a difference, but it's something to be aware of nonetheless.

Comment: @TomLord Ahh I see! I'll take this into great consideration for big-data apps then; thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: if `Hunts#confirmed` is a database column:**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hunt
  scope :ready, -> { joins(:hunt).where(hunts: { confirmed: true }) }
end
```

In this case, `Team.ready` will return `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

**Solution: If `Hunts#confirmed?` is a NOT a database column:**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hunt
  scope :ready, -> { includes(:hunts).select(&:ready?) }
end
```

In this case, `Team.ready` will return an `Array`

You need to be aware that the second solution is looping over the Team records calling `ready?` on each of them while the first is performing a database query. First is more efficient.